# MySQL LIKE matching whole numbers only

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I am trying to get the records from my database that have a number in a vertical pipe separated value.

I have my query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM level_3 

WHERE 
    date_end = -6 

AND 
    ccode = 'GB'

AND ( 
    responsible LIKE '%5%' OR 
    accountable LIKE '%5%' OR 
    consulted LIKE '%5%' OR 
    informed LIKE '%5%'
    )
```

And here are the results:

```
date_end    ccode    responsible    accountable    consulted    informed
-6          GB       |6|            |6|            |8|9|15|     |8|
-6          GB       |6|5|          |6|            |8|          |16|
```

However it is matching 15 for **LIKE %5%** but I only want it to match the exact number. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: If you can, [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) your database. Storing multiple values in one single field is very bad practice.

Comment: I would but unfortunately this isn't my database. Do you mean having a separate table with each number stored as a new row?

Comment: Just had a read through your link, yes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM level_3 

WHERE 
    date_end = -6 

AND 
    ccode = 'GB'

AND ( 
    responsible LIKE '%|5|%' OR 
    accountable LIKE '%|5|%' OR 
    consulted LIKE '%|5|%' OR 
    informed LIKE '%|5|%'
    )
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks! This is probably why the data has a start and end vertical pipe.

Answer (score 2):

There is a regular expression pendant to LIKE.

```
SELECT * FROM level_3 
WHERE date_end = -6 
AND ccode = 'GB'
AND ( 
    responsible REGEXP '\|[0-9]+\|' OR 
    ...
)
```

(Remark for other uses: use `'^ ... $'` for total matching from begin `^` to end `$`.)

Answer (score 0):

Whay you would like is something like

```
Where concat('|',responsible,'|') like '%|5|%'
```

Comment: Oow the columns already start and end with pipe? Ok never mind then